# File command not finding the right info from an iso file

Tags: files, iso

When I run

```
file archlinux-2015.11.01-dual.iso
```

it responds with

```
archlinux-2015.11.01-dual.iso: x86 boot sector
```

when I know it should be responding with something like

```
archlinux-2015.11.01-dual.iso: DOS/MBR boot sector ISO 9660 CD-ROM 
filesystem data (DOS/MBR boot sector) 'ARCH_201511' (bootable);
partition 2 : ID=0xef, start-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), end-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), startsector 252, 63488 sectors
```

Why isn't `file` working properly?

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: `file` on October's image: `archlinux-2015.10.01-dual.iso: DOS/MBR boot sector ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data 'ARCH_201510' (bootable); partition 2 : ID=0xef, start-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), end-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), startsector 172, 63488 sectors`. What's the output of `file -v`?

Comment: `archlinux-2015.11.01-dual.iso file-5.14 magic file from /etc/magic:/usr/share/misc/magic`

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall file`, see if that avails. I don't think the difference is between the two ISOs.

Comment: No, this did not make a difference. :(

Comment: Do you have other ISOs on which to test `file`?